# Javascript sort an array of objects by comparing with a certain condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like this:

```
obj = [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 17, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'red', 'position':3},
        {'name': 'Sam', 'age': 19, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'red', 'position':2},
        {'name': 'Harry', 'age': 16, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'red', 'position':1},
        {'name': 'Charles', 'age': 19, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'blue', 'position':2},
        {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 21, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'blue', 'position':3},
        {'name': 'Mike', 'age': 23, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'blue', 'position':1}]
```

What I wish to achieve is, sort the array of objects in ascending order by position for all the objects with a similar color. My expected output is this:

```
 obj = [{'name': 'Harry', 'age': 16, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'red', 'position':1},
        {'name': 'Sam', 'age': 19, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'red', 'position':2},
        {'name': 'Tom', 'age': 17, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'red', 'position':3},
        {'name': 'Mike', 'age': 23, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'blue', 'position':1}
        {'name': 'Charles', 'age': 19, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'blue', 'position':2},
        {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 21, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'blue', 'position':3}]
```

My approach:
I have the set of unique colors like this:

```
unique_colors = ['red', 'blue'];
for (var i in unique_colors){
  obj.forEach(function(x){
  if (i === x.colors){
  obj.sort((a,b) => a.position - b.position);
}
}
});
```

But that didn't work. Please assist me where I am going wrong. Thanks a lot in advance. Sorry if its trivial, am still learning javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` function to get the index of the color and compare

```js
let objArr = [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 17, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'red', 'position':3},
        {'name': 'Sam', 'age': 19, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'red', 'position':2},
        {'name': 'Harry', 'age': 16, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'red', 'position':1},
        {'name': 'Charles', 'age': 19, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'blue', 'position':2},
        {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 21, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'blue', 'position':3},
        {'name': 'Mike', 'age': 23, 'gender': 'male', 'color':'blue', 'position':1}];
        
let colors = ['red','blue']

objArr.sort((a,b) => {
  let idxA = colors.indexOf(a.color);
  let idxB = colors.indexOf(b.color) ;
  return idxA === idxB ? a.position-b.position : idxA - idxB 
});

console.log(objArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a following customize sort algorithm:

```js
const obj = [{
    name: "Tom",
    age: 17,
    gender: "male",
    color: "red",
    position: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Sam",
    age: 19,
    gender: "male",
    color: "red",
    position: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Harry",
    age: 16,
    gender: "male",
    color: "red",
    position: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Charles",
    age: 19,
    gender: "male",
    color: "blue",
    position: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Fred",
    age: 21,
    gender: "male",
    color: "blue",
    position: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 23,
    gender: "male",
    color: "blue",
    position: 1
  },
];

const result = obj.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.color === b.color) {
    return a.position - b.position;
  } else return a.color - b.color;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: _"You need..."_ - Please search for duplicates first...